# Adding and removing onclick prop from a href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add and remove `onclick` listener from `a herf` element.
so:

```
var currentValue = $('#in-new-value').val();

if(!Pattern.test(currentValue)){        
   //disable click
   $("#aSubmitButton").prop('onclick', null);
}else{
   //enable click               
   $("#aSubmitButton").prop('onclick', 'javascript:CheckUserInput();');             
}
```

and my element:

```
<a id="aSubmitButton" onclick="javascript:CheckUserInput();" class="btn_commit big_btn fll"</a>
```

Disabling works, but enabling it back not.

Comment: It's probably easier to use JQuery's `on` and `off` to add and remove event listeners. http://api.jquery.com/off/ http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery `click()` for this..

```js
var currentValue = $('#in-new-value').val();

$("#aSubmitButton").click(function(){
  if(Pattern.test(currentValue)){
    CheckUserInput();
  } else {
    return false;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add and remove a class and do this in jquery:

```
$('.yourClass').click(function({
//do stuff
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
$( element ).off ( event );
```

ref: [ http://api.jquery.com/off/ ]

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to mix click handlers with html

You can give handlers as

add a click handler when ever you need it as

```
var currentValue = $('#in-new-value').val();

if(!Pattern.test(currentValue)){ 

$('a').click(function () {
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When enabling use `.attr()` instead of `.prop()`

```
$("#aSubmitButton").attr('onclick', 'javascript:CheckUserInput();');
```

You can also use it when disabling it:

```
$("#aSubmitButton").attr('onclick', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another way to remove event-handler from your element. I suggest you use unbind() and bind() function.

In the simplest case, with no arguments, .unbind() removes all handlers attached to the elements:

```
$("#aSubmitButton").unbind();
```

This version removes the handlers regardless of type. To be more
   precise, we can pass an event type:

```
$( "#aSubmitButton").unbind( "click" );
```

for add event use bind() like this :

```
$( "#aSubmitButton" ).bind( "click", function() {
 //your stuff
});
```

**Note** : As of jQuery 3.0, .unbind() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the **.off()** method since jQuery 1.7, so can use :

```
$('#aSubmitButton').off('click');
```

for more help :
http://api.jquery.com/unbind/